# How do I calculate overall probability of an occurrence with unique probabilities at different attempts?

Tags: probability

cenario: You have marbles of 2 colors, red and blue. You put one red and one blue marble in a bag and take one at random. The probability of getting a red marble is obviously 50%. But then you add 5 more blue marbles in the bag and take one at random again. The probability of getting red for that attempt alone is obviously 1/7, but how do I calculate the overall probability of getting a red marble at least once through both attempts whereas each attempt has a different probability?

Attempt 1: 2 marbles, 1 red, 1 blue

Attempt 2: 7 marbles, 2 red, 5 blue

Attempt 3: 10 marbles, 3 red, 7 blue

It doesn't take a mathematician to figure out the probabilities for each individual attempt, but in the given scenario, how is the *overall* probability calculated?

By the way, I already figured it out using pictures: 105/140 chance. But is there some formula I can use for such math problems like above?

Comment: Multiply the ratios, and then subtract from 1. $$\frac12\cdot\frac57\cdot\frac7{10}=\frac{35}{140}$$$$1-\frac{35}{140}=\frac{105}{140}$$Obviously, you need to reduce this fraction.

Comment: You can do this directly or you can do this indirectly depending on what is easiest at the time.  For this, try finding the chance that you never drew a red marble.  The probability you want is the opposite of this.  Alternatively, doing it directly you can recall inclusion-exclusion tells us that $Pr(A\cup B\cup C) = Pr(A)+Pr(B)+Pr(C)-Pr(A\cap B)-Pr(A\cap C)-Pr(B\cap C)+Pr(A\cap B\cap C)$

Comment: Alternatively still, you can approach with $Pr(A\cup B\cup C) = Pr(A)+Pr(A^c)Pr(B\mid A^c)+Pr(A^c)Pr(B^c\mid A^c)Pr(C\mid A^c\cap B^c)$.  There are many different approaches.  It is good to familiarize yourself with the most common ones as this lets you pick whatever is most suitable at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Just note that $$1-p = (1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_3)$$

This simply says that for the experiment to fail, you must fail on each attempt.

So the probability of success on the combined experiment is

$$p = 1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_3).$$

(Here, $p_j$ is the probability of success (drawing a red marble) on the $j^{\textrm{th}}$ attempt. I also assume you are drawing with replacement.)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can break it into cases:

$$(\mbox{happens on first attempt})+(\mbox{doesn't happen on first attempt} )\cdot(\mbox{happens on second attempt} ) +(\mbox{doesn't happen on first or second attempt})\cdot (\mbox{happens on third attempt}) $$